# SharePoint DB Server - CPU usage 1 to 5%. RAM is almost 100% at all the time

Tags: 2010, sql-server, database, sql

On the SQL server box. I bumped the RAM to 24 GB and allocated 20GB for SQL Server. Now the performance looks like attached print shot. I see there is barely 1 GB RAM available and only 31 Free. Is this normal? How does your perfmon looks like?

[image]

Comment: Is this a SharePoint question?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is out of scope of this site as defined in the Help section.

Comment: Yes. It is SharePoint question. I forgot to mention this db server dedicated to SharePoint.

Comment: This question is off topic, since it's all about SQL Server. You are probably better off posting it on Serverfault.com where they deal with Server specific questions. However, you need to clarify what your question is more specific, since it's a bit vague at the moment.

Comment: But it is easily answered, in SQL Management Studio, login to your server, select the database server, right click and choose Properties. Under Memory -set a maximum limit of memory that gives the server enough slack to do normal server stuff. If this is not set, or equal to the amount of memory in the server, SQL will eat it all

Comment: Robert: this is what I did to allocate 20GB to sql and left 4gb for the server. is it normal for sql to hog entire allocated RAM.

Answer (score 1):

As the change in the allocation should not require a SQL restart I would guess that you have something else hogging the rest of the RAM. Look into the Proccesses tab and see if the culprit is visible there.
As a best practice, nothing except SQL should be running there.